# How to cast an array to an array with another primitive type

Tags: java, performance, arrays, casting, primitive-types

Can someone complete the code on an easy way?

```
float[] floats = {...}; // create an array
// Now I want to create a new array of ints from the arrays floats
int[] ints = ????;
```

I know I can simply cast element by element to a new array. But is it possible on an easier way?

Thanks

Comment: I think you have to write a loop, and it's maddening that the Java "for ... in" construct is so weak that you can't even use it here in this common scenario.

Comment: Theoretically, you could create a java.lang.Number-Array, add integers to it and use .floatValue and .intValue as you need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't do it any other way for your float to int example than individually casting each and every element.

I quickly Googled this which turned up somebody with a similar problem that more or less corroborates what I've said:

http://www.java-forums.org/advanced-java/11255-type-casting-array.html

I would recommend just individually casting the elements. It's guaranteed to work and be easy to understand for a future developer. Any sort of "cast all at once" code would probably just be doing that behind the scenes anyway.

Comment: Java does not allow casting array types to sub-classes (e.g. `String[] sarray = (String[]) new Object[10];`). Attempting to do this results in a runtime `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Good to know. I removed the incorrect statement from my answer.

Comment: "Any sort of "cast all at once" code would probably just be doing that behind the scenes anyway." Actually, it could use native SSE/AVX for much higher performance, just like System.arraycopy(). Strange that Java doesn't have such a method.

Comment: I've searched extensively on the topic of array casting in Java, in order to cast primitive array types to bytes so they can be dumped to a file. Being a C programmer, I was pretty shocked to realize there's no easy way to do it without a for loop. The only alternative I found was starting with a `ByteBuffer`, and then creating my array (e.g. float[]) as a view into the `ByteBuffer`, e.g. `bb.asFloatBuffer`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this directly. Based on the context of how this array is created in used, you may want to consider using an array of a wrapper class, where your setter accepts a float and getter returns an int.

This would be ideal, if it is practical in your situation, because you get to hide the conversion from the client code.